# How to increase font size in webView loadRequest in Swift

Tags: webview

How to increase font size in webView loadRequest  in Swift.
I am using HTML code in my project.

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "HtmlCode", ofType: "html")!) as URL) as URLRequest)
```

while run this code Font size is too small.How to I  increase the font sizes.

[image]

Comment: Hi i found the solution.Need To be added
webView.scalesPageToFit = false